# No muestra valor en ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in result">                            
   {{value}}  => ESTO LO MUESTRA
<input type="radio" name="rGrpLab" ng-model="rGrpLab" value="key">
</div>

{{rGrpLab}} => ESTO NO LO MUESTRA
```

Se que es porque esta dentro del `ng-repeat`, pero no se como obtener ese valor.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A veces AngularJS (Angular 1) tiene problemas con el scope. Te recomiendo que conviertas rGrpLab en un diccionario y trates lo siguiente

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in result">                            
   {{value}}
<input type="radio" name="rGrpLab" ng-model="rGrpLab.value" value="key">
</div>

{{rGrpLab.value}}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, he hecho lo que has dicho y funcionando #Juanin

Comment: De nada. Podrías marcar mi respuesta como la respuesta aceptada?

Comment: como se hace eso? soy nuevo en este foro

Comment: Aquí sale cómo se hace: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers